# PHP, Sort/merge multidimensional array by other (smaller) array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$original=[];
$original[]=['value'=>'a','count'=>10];
$original[]=['value'=>'b','count'=>15];
$original[]=['value'=>'c','count'=>23];
$original[]=['value'=>'d','count'=>40];
$original[]=['value'=>'e','count'=>25];
```

And this array that contains the items that should be at the beginning of the $original array:

```
$sort=['d','c'];
```

So the result should eventually be:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'value' => 'd',
        'count' => (int) 40
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'value' => 'c',
        'count' => (int) 23
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'value' => 'a',
        'count' => (int) 10
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'value' => 'b',
        'count' => (int) 15
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'value' => 'e',
        'count' => (int) 25
    ],
]
```

Using a simple for loop this is doable, but is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Is your `$sort` array supposed to be multidimensional? What kind of behavior do you expect for example for `$sort = [['d', 'c'], ['b', 'a']]`?

Comment: No. $sort only contains the value keys, nothing else

Comment: But in your example it's `$sort = [['d','c']]`.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)

```
$priority = ['d', 'c'];
usort($original, function ($a, $b) use ($priority) {

    $prioA = array_search($a['value'], $priority);
    $prioB = array_search($b['value'], $priority);

    if ($prioA !== false && $prioB !== false) {
        if ($prioA < $prioB) return -1;
        return 1;
    }
    if ($prioA !== false) return -1;
    if ($prioB !== false) return 1;

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! But how am I going to get $sort in there? Using ['d','c'] is not an option because this array is dynamic

Comment: I've updated with passing `$priority` to the closure